# DB2:Proc Inside Proc is not returning anything

Tags: db2, procedure

I am getting a DB2 proc issue. Don't know where I am doing the mistake.

I have 2 SPs. SP1 and SP2.

I am calling SP1 from SP2 however SP2 is not returning any output (except return 0).

Can you please check what is the issue.

I know I can rename the SP1 to SP2 but there is some requirement that's why I need to call the SP1 from SP2 only.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1()
SPECIFIC SP1
RESULT SETS 1
READS SQL DATA
NOT DETERMINISTIC
NULL CALL
LANGUAGE SQL EXTERNAL ACTION
INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
P1:BEGIN
  DECLARE X CURSOR 
  WITH RETURN FOR
  SELECT A.* FROM EMP A;
  OPEN X;
END P1;

CREATE PROCEDURE SP2()
SPECIFIC SP2
RESULT SETS 1
READS SQL DATA
NOT DETERMINISTIC
NULL CALL
LANGUAGE SQL EXTERNAL ACTION
INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
P2:BEGIN
  CALL SP1();
END P2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want SP2 to return the result-set from nested SP1 back to the requesting application (= the client) without any changes and without any processing.  If that is true, then inside SP1 you must declare your cursor 'WITH RETURN TO CLIENT'. This allows the result-set to pass through SP1 .

If instead you want to *process* the result-set from SP1 inside of SP2 then you must use a result-set locator for the nested-procedure and allocate a cursor for that and process the cursor in the normal way.

Refer to the Db2 online Knowledge Center for your version of Db2 and your DB2-server platform for more details of these statements.

Comment: Wow.. 'WITH RETURN TO CLIENT' worked like a charm.. Thanks a lot Mao.. You are a rock star for me..